# extract value and read as variable

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting

```
Thu Feb 19 10:42:50: Submitted from host <iitmlogin5-ib0>, CWD <$HOME/Bipin/JAS_Data/Big_Domain/128np_IC/Normal_queue>, Output File <file.stdout.159375>, Error File <file.stderr.159375>, Exclusive Execution, 128 Task(s), Requested Resources <span[ptile=16]>; RUNLIMIT
```

from the above given line, I want to extract the values No of tasks i.e '128' and '16' ptile. want to read this values in variable

Task = 128
ptile = 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep -P` with `read`:

```
read task ptile < <(grep -oP '.*\K\b\d+(?= Task)|.*ptile=\K\d+' file | tr '\n' ' ')

echo "[$task] - [$ptile]"
[128] - [16]
```

Comment: Thanks, but inside script is not working

read task ptile < <(grep -oP '.*\K\b\d+(?= Task)|.*ptile=\K\d+' ./159375.out | tr '\n' ' ')

./ai.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Comment: Make sure you are running it in BASH

Comment: #!/bin/bash
sudo bjobs -l 159375 | sed -n '/Submitted/,/^$/p' | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/                     //g'> ./159375.out
if
grep -q "Exclusive Execution" ./159375.out
then
read task ptile < <(grep -oP '.*\K\b\d+(?= Task)|.*ptile=\K\d+' ./159375.out | tr '\n' ' ')
Nodes_Required=$($tasks/$ptile)
echo $Nodes_Required

Comment: Don't post code in comments as it is impossible to read. Edit your question and provide it there. Besides I can only test the commands with the data that is provided in question.

Comment: I think it should be `(grep -oP ...` not `(ggrep -oP ...)`

Comment: Yes @Jotne: I just had `ggrep` (gnu-grep) separately installed on my OSX :)